# AJAX request error in IE, invalid argument

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I send an ajax request, it works in all browser except in IE. And not IE6, but IE10!

What error do am I getting? Here is the error thrown in the IE's console:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070057, Invalid argument. 
order
```

And here is the ajax code:

```
$('#sn_file').live("change", function(){
    var item = $("#loader"),
    loader = $("<div>", {
        "text" : "Uploading file",
        "class" : "ajaxloader"
    }).appendTo( item ),
    form = $(this).parents('form');

form.ajaxSubmit({
         success: function( responseText, statusText, xhr )
         {
             var result = responseText;
             if( isNaN(result) )
             {
                 $("#left-file-upload").html( result );
                 $("#orderform").fadeIn();
                 loader.remove();
             }
             else
             {
                switch( result )
                {
                    case '1':
                    var msg = "";
                    break;

                    case '2':
                    var msg = "";
                    break;
            case '3':
                    var msg = "";
                    break;

                    case '4':
                    var msg = "";
                    break;


                }

                msg = "<div class=\"err-box\"><p>" + msg + "</p></div>";
                item.html(msg)
            }
         }
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with similar ajax request. 
Try and add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

into "head" section (ie10 and ie9 are almost the same).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't works. Neither with EmulateIE9, neither with EDGE values.